# Handling path change of a SQLite database file

Tags: c, sqlite

After I open a database file with `sqlite3_open()` and before I close it with `sqlite3_close()`, does SQLite provide any mechanism to handle changes to the file path of the database file?

My experiment shows that the connection to the file is, by default, not maintained if I rename/move the file in Unix. After renaming/moving, any further `sqlite3_step()` results in a `disk I/O error`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such mechanism.

You must not move the database file, or reopen the database afterwards.